# Обработка нажатий на динамически созданые элементы

Tags: java, android, android-on-click

Есть класc экземпляры которого - динамически сгенерированные элементы меню

```
public class MenuElement extends RelativeLayout {

public static int ALARM = 1;
public static int WARNING = 2;
public RelativeLayout layout;
private ImageView alarmLogo;
private TextView alarmText;
private int alarmType = 0;
private String Type = "";
public String Track = "";
public String Zone = "";

public MenuElement(Context context, String tr, String zn, int alarmtype) {
    super(context);
    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.menuElement);
    Track = tr;
    Zone = zn;
    alarmType = alarmtype;
    initComponent();
}

private void initComponent() {
    LayoutInflater inflayer = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflayer.inflate(R.layout.element_layout, this);
    alarmLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.alarmLogo);
    alarmText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alarmText);
    updateFields();
}

private void updateFields() {
    switch (alarmType) {
        case 1:
            alarmLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_alarm_icon);
            Type = "ALARM";
            break;
        case 2:
            alarmLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_warning_icon);
            Type = "WARNING";
            break;
        default:
            Toast.makeText(parrnet, "Wrong alarm type", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
    String textToFormat = getResources().getString(R.string.stringtoformat);
    alarmText.setText(String.format(textToFormat, Type, Track, Zone));
}
}
```

В определенный момент генерируется несколько экземпляров класса.

```
    private void GenerateAlarms(int type, List<Track> trk){
    for (int i = 0; i < trk.size(); i++){
        final MenuElement element = new MenuElement(getApplicationContext(), trk.get(i).id, trk.get(i).zone, type);
    }
    }
```

Как правильно обработать нажатие на один из сгенерированных элементов чтоб дальше работать с его параметрами?

Comment: и код, конечно, читать тяжело. Он написан абсолютно не по стандартам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сразу после создания установите ему `OnClickListener`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < trk.size(); i++){
    final MenuElement element = new MenuElement(getApplicationContext(), trk.get(i).id, trk.get(i).zone, type);
    element.setOnCLickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        ...
    }) 
}
```